# DISTINCT SUM with MysQL JOIN

Tags: mysql, sum, aggregate

I have two tables tableA and tableB.

```
tableA
-------
ID  sid     amount

1   swerdd  20    
2   swerdd  30    
3   fdff    40

tableB
------

new_id  token    date

10      swerdd  2014 -10-12    
11      swerdd  2014 -10-13    
12      swerdd  2014 -10-13
```

Now when I use the query

```
SELECT * FROM tableA JOIN tableB on tableA.sid = tableB.token
```

is giving multiple rows and so my other query

```
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM tableA JOIN tableB on tableA.sid = tableB.token
```

is giving wrong results. How can I select the DISTINCT SUM ?

EDIT : The thing is that I have a many to many relation here as the sid and token is repeating. So in a nutshell the question is how can I calculate distinct sum in a many to many join

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: I need to get the SUM as 90. But it is different when I use join

Comment: I don't think there is a reward_amount field on the table

Comment: I mean the amount field. I just edited the question.

Comment: I think you need to edit your question and display your expected output.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague to say the least. Your expected output is 90? Are you simply looking for `select sum(amount) from tablea`?

Comment: The thing is that I have a many to many relation here. That is the sid and token in repeating in both the tables.

Comment: Yes, I see the relation, but I don't see what this has to do with your expected result of 90. If you want to select the sum for tablea then do so. Tableb has nothing to do at all with it. Just select from tablea. That's the solution. What you are saying is like: "I wanted apples, so I bought apples and bananas, but when I got home I suddenly noticed that I got apples and bananas when I only wanted apples." How are we supposed to help here???

Answer (score 2):

A couple of approaches that don't involve a join operation...

An `EXISTS` predicate...

```
SELECT SUM(a.reward_amount) 
  FROM tableA a
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tableB b WHERE b.token = a.sid)
```

An `IN (subquery)` predicate...

```
SELECT SUM(a.reward_amount) 
  FROM tableA a
 WHERE a.sid IN (SELECT b.token FROM tableB b)
```

For a join operation, one option is to use an inline view to get a distinct list of token...

```
SELECT SUM(a.reward_amount)
  FROM tableA a
  JOIN ( SELECT b.token
           FROM tableB b
          GROUP BY b.token
       ) c
    ON c.token = a.sid
```

Answer (score -1):

To get distinct sum you can use below query

```
SELECT reward_amount
FROM tableA 
     JOIN tableB on tableA.sid = tableB.token
GROUP BY reward_amount;
```